# how to unit test a class that uses a factory?

Tags: java, factory

If I have a class Foo that gets objects from a factory, how do I unit test Foo?

```
class Foo {
  void doSth(){
    AnObject object = Factory.instance().getObject();
    object.doSth();
  }
}
```

I'm always going to have to actually call Factory in my unit test of Foo, aren't I?

Is that where spring dependency injection would give me an advantage, because I can just do

```
class Foo {
  setFactory(Factory factory){
    this.factory = factory;
  }
  void doSth(){
    AnObject object = factory.getObject();
    object.doSth();
  }
}
```

Or is there a workaround in a non-spring world?

Comment: Dependency injection is exactly how I would unit test a class that needs a factory. That has nothing to do with spring.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you saying that you would have a set() method for adding the factory to the class ie my second code sample? I see lots of examples of how to use the factory method that have the static call of my first example, but I don't see how you can test that without calling the real Factory and getting back the real AnObject.. Do I have that right? Why don't the example of factory show you how to use it in a best practice way if that's the case?

Comment: Those are some good questions :-) Anyway, I would always inject a factory instance (like in your second snipped), either via a setter, or in the constructor (the question there would be: can the object exist without the factory? If no: pass it in the constructor.) As you say, the factory is often used in the static variant, but when you write code with testing in mind, that's not a good practise.

Comment: Thanks, Heuster - very much appreciated. I also found this article which suggests the possibility of using a factory method within the class and then overriding the factory method in test http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-mocktest/index.html that avoids having to do something special in the objects that create foo. Meh, I have to look at this some more.. Thanks again for your insights..